# Remove/Hide Terminal window from custom Application List entry

Tags: command-line

*First off, apologies if this is not the right place for this specific question, but new to both the site and the OS in question.*

**-System Details-**
OS: Xubuntu 14.04 (xfce)

**Question:** I have manually added a new program to my Applications List, by creating a new file with the following script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_AU]=/home/username/programdir/programexe.gif
Icon=/home/username/programdir/programexe.gif
Exec=/home/username/programdir/programexe
Name[en_AU]=ProgramName
Comment[en_AU]=Program Name
Name=ProgramName
Comment=Program Name
```

This file is than placed in **/usr/share/applications**

This program requires SUDO access to launch correctly, which I was able to accomplish by editing the following lines:

```
Terminal=true
Exec=sudo /home/username/programdir/programexe
```

This causes a Terminal window to open where I can enter the SUDO pass, and allow the program to launch fully.

**Issue:** Once the Terminal window opens, it remains open and will only close when the program is shutdown.

I have tried setting the line **"Terminal:true"** to **"Terminal:false"**, but this effectively stops the program as the Terminal window will not launch during startup for the SUDO pass entry.

Is there a way for me to get the Terminal window to close once the pass has been entered, so that it is not constantly present?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
TH

Comment: Replace `sudo` with `gksudo` and use `Terminal:false`, maybe you have to install `gksu` first: `sudo apt-get install gksu`

Comment: Hi A.B, Your suggestion worked brilliantly! Thank you for the fast response and the assistance.